# Roundoff error in the yticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

The following MWE

```tex
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pgfplots,xparse}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17, % Specify the compatibility version
  nice_axis/.style={
        xlabel={$t/T_c$},
        ylabel={$p_{BOC \left( 1,1 \right)}\left( t \right)\cdot \sqrt{T_c}$},
        % title={Triangle Function},
        grid=both,
        axis lines=box,
        samples=101,
        domain=-2:2,
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=1,
        ymax=1.2,
        ymin=-1.2,
        ytick={-1, -0.8, ..., 1},
        legend pos=outer north east,
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    nice_axis,
  ]
    \addplot[black, thick, mark=none] coordinates {
        (-1,0)
        (-0.5,0)
        (-0.5,1)
        (0,1)
        (0,-1)
        (0.5,-1)
        (0.5,0)
        (1,0)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Yields

[image]

As far as I could see in in other pots, it is due to roundoff error. How to set `ytick` so that I don't get the zero-imprecision error? I tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315571/rounding-off-before-plotting) but it seems to work for `table` only.

Comment: Could one start at $-5*0.2$ instead of $-1$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen unfortunately no. Although 0.2 isn't exactly representable, 5*0.2 rounds to 1.0 exactly. You could say the problem happens in the middle: `0.2 + 0.2` and `0.6 - 0.2` are *very* slightly different numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rounded `yticklabel` by

```
yticklabel style = {/pgf/number format/fixed},
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pgfplots,xparse}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.18, % Specify the compatibility version
  nice_axis/.style={
        xlabel={$t/T_c$},
        ylabel={$p_{BOC \left( 1,1 \right)}\left( t \right)\cdot \sqrt{T_c}$},
 %       title={Pulse Function},
        grid=both,
        axis lines=box,
        domain=-1:1,
        ytick={-1, -0.8, ..., 1},
        yticklabel style = {/pgf/number format/fixed},
        xmin=-1,    xmax=1,
        legend pos=outer north east,
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[nice_axis]
    \addplot[thick, mark=none] coordinates {
        (-1,0)
        (-0.5,0)
        (-0.5,1)
        (0,1)
        (0,-1)
        (0.5,-1)
        (0.5,0)
        (1,0)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I guess this is more idiomatic tikz, I wonder if I should delete mine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, no. It show me another way how to handle  number formatting in `pgfplots` ... +1

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You can use `\fpeval` to round to 2 decimal places.

Just add

```
        yticklabel={$\fpeval{0 - round(-\tick,2)}$},
```

The double negation avoids rounding to -0 in this case.